# Uploading a CSV file as Google Sheet using Android SDK

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I have an Android app that allows users to export a .csv file to Google Drive so that they can edit it and then reimport the file into Android.

This used to work perfectly with the old Google Docs api's.  I upgraded from that old API to an early version of Google Drive last year and was able to get it working well enough.  Now, when I upgraded to the latest version, this feature of my app is effectively broken.  I think it's a combination of the SDK permissions and breaking out Google Sheets from Google Drive.

What happens is I upload a file with this meta data:

```
    MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                                                        .setTitle(fileName)
                                                        .setMimeType("text/csv")
                                                        .setStarred(true)
                                                        .build();
```

The uploaded file then has a blue Google Docs icon.  When a user access Google Drive to edit it they can only "preview" the document.  While they are previewing it they can "Open" the document using Google Sheets which then creates a new document (this new document has the Green Google Sheets icon) and since Google SDK has this new "Feature" (quoted from: https://developers.google.com/drive/android/queries ):

> Note: The Android Drive API only works with the
>   https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file scope. This means that only
>   files which a user has opened or created with your application can be
>   matched by a query.

The new file has can not be seen by my, so the user's edits can't be retrieved.

Is there someway I can upload it directly as a Google Sheets file?  Or maybe another solution I've missed entirely?

***Edits***

Here is an example on how I am uploading my code using the Google Drive SDK:

In the constructor of my AsyncTask I create the google client:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(activity)
                            .addApi(Drive.API)
                            .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                            .build();
mGoogleApiClient.connect();
```

Then in the doInBackground method I do something like this:

```
DriveApi.DriveContentsResult cResult = Drive.DriveApi.newDriveContents(mGoogleApiClient).await();

OutputStream os = cResult.getDriveContents().getOutputStream();
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(f);

//write the input stream to the output stream
....

DriveFileResult exportResult = Drive.DriveApi.getRootFolder(mGoogleApiClient)
                                                             .createFile(mGoogleApiClient, changeSet, cResult.getDriveContents())
                                                             .await();
```

It's pretty simple (once you figure it out) there just doesn't seem to be away to tell the SDK that I want this document to be a "Google Sheet" instead of a "Google Doc"

Thanks!

-Aaron

Comment: my case is that import=false (which is the default). Set import=true

Comment: Is that using the web api for google drive? I don't see anywhere in the Android SDK (developers.google.com/drive/android) that let's you set a property called import. I updated the question to include a code same of the Android SDK.

Comment: As @Rivero mentions below, to do this you need to use the convert parameter which isn't currently supported in the Android API. Could you file a feature request on the API issue tracker outlining your use case? https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/ In the meantime I suggest continuing to use the Java API client.

Answer (score 2):

You should convert the original explicitly into a Spreadsheet, otherwise it will end up as a straight upload into your Drive account. Try the following code:

```
java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File(csvfilepath);
FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("text/csv", fileContent);

// File's metadata.
File body = new File();
body.setTitle(fileContent.getName());
body.setMimeType("text/csv");

Insert request = service.files().insert(body, mediaContent);
request.setConvert(true);
File file = request.execute();
```

Comment: I think that is for the google-api-client api isn't it?  Google is asking Android developers to use the new Drive SDK (https://developers.google.com/drive/android/) to access google drive with threats of deprecation and disablement.